# CAN-BUS signals of Ford Transit needed

Tags: ford, can-bus

I'm looking for the specification of the **CAN-BUS** signals for the **Ford Transit connect 2013**. Does anyone know who might have done this reverse engineering already?

Specifically, I'm looking for signals related to fuel consumption for this car.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not an expert on Transits, but I suspect you'll need a bit more information than that - what age of Transit for a start? I suspect they are proprietary, but you've presumably worked that out already as you mention reverse engineering...

Comment: @NickC I asume they are proprietary, didn't find anything on the net about that. I edited the question regarding year of the car. thanks

Comment: On my Ford Fiesta MK6 I sinfed some data from bus: http://sergeyk.kiev.ua/avto/ford_CAN_bus/ , but I have not full information about description of Ford CAN ID messages :(
OpenXC - is "black box", which convert CAN messages to a other simple format (which have open informations).
I search fuel information on CAN-bus, but still not have simple solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can petition Ford to release it, as they have for the Focus, Escape, and some other cars with their [OpenXC](http://developer.ford.com/develop/openxc) SDK

Alternatively, you can try to hack the OpenXC to work with it. I imagine the protocols are there, just slightly different.